# Pass Function from Another Window Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, parent

I am requiring some JavaScript functions to be sent back to the parent window and having difficulty.  I have created a sample to iterate what I am attempting to do.  But basically I need to show and hide a DIV on the parent window by executing a function from the separate window.

The first Snippet is Page1.html,

```js
function newWin() {
  window.open("page2.html", "New_Win");
}

function toggle_vis(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#frame {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#inner {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frame"><button onclick="newWin()">Open New Window</button>
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code from Page2.html.

```js
function test(){
   parent.document.innerHTML.toggle_vis('inner');
}
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<button onclick="test()">Show/Hide Parent Div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `opener`, not  `parent`

Comment: Thank you, can you clarify?

Comment: Change `parent.document.innerHTML.toggle_vis('inner');` to `opener.document.innerHTML.toggle_vis('inner');`

Comment: toggle_vis is not a property of innerHTML

Comment: I wonder if the toggle_vis function also needs a reference to the opener's document object.

Comment: James, xavvvier hit it right on the head, window.opener.toggle_vis('inner'); works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reference the opener window with the `window.opener` object, therefore:

```
function test(){
   window.opener.toggle_vis('inner');
}
```